# WITH Select issue on not returning same data as specific values

Tags: oracle, select, datatable, with-statement

When I do: WITH something AS (select tbl1.value1, tbl1.value2, tbl1.value3 from tbl1 table1)

for a table with 14 values for  those 3 variables, when using the SOMETHING in another select I get 0  returned rows.

IF I manually define the  values individually in the

```
WITH something AS (
  select 'Manual1' as value1, 'Manual2' as value2, 'Manual3' as value3 
  FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'Manual1' as value1, 'Manual2' as  value2, 'Manual3' as value3'
)
```

line 2,3,4-14 etc.. you get it, more UNION ALLs for the manual values to manually print the values from the table in the top line.

Under what  circumstances is this treated differently in another select? the values are EXACTLY the same in the table, but if I manually define them, my other select is working and showing a count of 14, and not 0 as when I am defining the values through the ref table above.

Any ideas? I can type the other select out but it will take a lot of time, and I  think there is something fundamental I am missing here.

I hate the UI of this site, it is outlined above.

Comment: Who knows. Actually, **I** don't. You used way too many *words*, but no example that illustrates what you are saying. You did post some semi-invalid statements (the first one will never compile; table alias should follow table name, not vice versa) but they don't illustrate anything. Please, edit the question and post real example: sample data, statements you execute, the way Oracle responds. Then we could work with that.

Comment: Yes, I messed up the order of the alias. Thanks big guy! I am asking in a blanket way if this is ever treated differently in order to not manually type a page of code. It's a simple question.

Comment: Yes. No. Maybe. I don't know. Because **I don't understand the question**. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't working because I had a line break above the next select I was going to use that invoked the WITH. I did not know this would be an issue.